# Why is material ui dropdown displaying all items in hover state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image: Material UI Dropdown]

```js
<IconMenu
  iconButtonElement={
    <IconButton touch>
      <NavigationExpandMoreIcon />
    </IconButton>}
>
  <MenuItem primaryText="Suspend" />
  <MenuItem primaryText="Reactivate" />
  <MenuItem primaryText="Cancel" />
</IconMenu>
```

The code above is how i use the react component

Comment: it looks like you have CSS style(s) defined elsewhere that are overriding the styles of the material-ui component. look for styles defined on "li", "div", and "span". if it's not obvious, try removing all references to external .css files, and test again. re-introduce the stylesheets one by one to find the culprit.  if you look at the documentation page for the dropdown menu and play with samples, if those render correctly there, then it must be CSS on your page overriding something.

Comment: @JeffMcCloud Thanks! You are absolutely right!